# Remove Comma From End Of String Advanced

Tags: php, mysql

I have read plenty of ways of removing the comma at the end of a string when doing basic queries but none of the basic stuff seems to be working with this particular script. Hopefully I'm just over thinking this. My script goes through the database and places the cities under the proper states but I need the last cities comma to be removed.

Here is the script I am using

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM markets WHERE id = 0 ORDER BY market_state";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$list = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
 $list[$r->market_state][$r->id]['market_cities'] = $r->market_cities;

}

foreach ($list as $market_state => $market_cities) {
echo '<h1>' . $market_state . '</h1>';

foreach ($market_cities as $cityId => $cityInfo) {
echo $cityInfo['market_cities']. ',';

// etc
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also let mysql make the work if you don't need this "cityId":

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT market_state,GROUP_CONCAT(market_cities) as market_cities FROM markets WHERE id = 0 GROUP BY market_state ORDER BY market_state";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$list = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $list[$r->market_state] = $r->market_cities;
}

foreach ($list as $market_state => $market_cities) {
    echo '<h1>' . $market_state . '</h1>';
    echo $market_cities;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative that works really well in this situation, is to make a string and simply trim off the last comma.

```
foreach ($market_cities as $cityId => $cityInfo) {
  $citystr .= $cityInfo['market_cities']. ',';
}
echo rtrim($citystr, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way is to do this...

```
$data = array_map(function($item) { return $item['market_cities']; }, $market_cities);
$output = implode(',', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the join function to output a comma-separated list from an array. So instead of:

```
foreach ($market_cities as $cityId => $cityInfo) {
    echo $cityInfo['market_cities']. ',';
    ...
    ...
}
```

It would look something like:

```
$cities = join(",", $market_cities);
echo $cities;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $cityInfo['market_cities'];
if(count($market_cities)<$i) {
    echo ",";
}
```

The simplest way of doing it.

Comment: Counting the same thing in a loop is redundant, you should assign it to a variable outside the loop.

Comment: You probably want to throw in the initialization and incrementing code to make it more clear.